# Verificar a existência de indice?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Existe alguma forma de usar um *Script* que verifique se um índice já existe em uma tabela?

Tenho o seguinte *script* que gera um índice em uma tabela:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [meu_indice] ON [dbo].[MinhaTabela]
(
[Id] ASC,
[Chave_Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF,     DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO
```

Só que como eu já criei o índice na tabela, se eu tentar rodar o script dá erro dizendo que o índice já foi criado.

Teria alguma forma de verificar se o índice já existe e só criar caso não exista?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que eu costumo fazer é um `select` na `sys.objects`

```
if (not exists (select null from sys.objects where name = 'meu_indice'))
```

o script completo fica

```
if (not exists (select null from sys.objects where name = 'meu_indice'))
    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [meu_indice] ON [dbo].[MinhaTabela]
    (
    [Id] ASC,
    [Chave_Id] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF,     DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
    GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar um `IF` assim:

```
If IndexProperty(Object_Id('MyTable'), 'MyIndex', 'IndexId') Is Null
```

Caso exista o indice irá retornar o `ID` caso não irá retorna `Null`.

Fonte: *[SoEn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689766/how-do-you-check-if-a-certain-index-exists-in-a-table)*

Comment: Você poderia colocar o script completo usando o código que passei?

Comment: Mesmo que eu tenha mais de um índice como no código que mandei? Tipo Id1 e Id2? Outra coisa, poderia colocar das duas formas? Acho que seria legal na resposta ter as duas formas!

Answer (score 0):

Utilize uma consulta na tabela sysindexes para verificar a existência.

Segue um exemplo:

`IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT id FROM sys.sysindexes where name = 'Nome_de_seu_indice')
BEGIN
   EXEC(
   '
    /****** coloque o seu indice aqui dentro do texto
     CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ...
    ...
    ...
')
END;`